# How to clear "last library visited"

Tags: document-library, image

One of my contributors can no longer add images to a Sharepoint page. When they attempt to add an image, Sharepoint "helps" them by trying to open the last library visited - which was part of a now deleted site. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the problem, the library what you have deleted still shows up in my home page last library visited dashboard, if this is the scenario we can get rid of this by cleaning the first and second level of recycle bin from SharePoint online

Go to the "RecycleBin.aspx" page by following the below navigation, there you will find your library, if you want to permanently delete, you can delete it otherwise you can restore the library from here.

[image: Recycle Bin1 - SharePoint Online]

If you are not able to trace the library from the "Recycle bin 1", we need to go to the "Recycle bin 2" by following the below navigation:

[image: Recycle Bin2 - SharePoint Online]

And you can follow the same like above recyclebin 1 step.

Notes:

- In SharePoint Online, the default retention time is 93 days for both
  site recycle bin (first stage) and site collection recycle bin
  (second stage).

RecycleBin retention setting Reference:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/extending-the-default-restoration-time-period-in-sharepoint/m-p/89945

Still,if your requirement is delete the library but after cleaning from RecycleBin stage 1 & 2, still appears in the last visited library report, then need to clean the browser cache.